# Fill ExposedDropdownMenu with data from other feature?

Tags: material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-mvvm, kotlin-flow

I am new to Android Development and I am just trying to build my first app. After watching several videos on YouTube and reading a lot of articles in the internet I have a first version of my application. I used jetpack compose with MVVM, Room database, flow and Material 3.

In the moment my app has two features ("manufacturers" and "products"). I now have the problem that I would like to add new products and therefor I need an ExposedDropdownMenu filled with items from the manufaturers feature, so that I will be able to store the manufacturer ID in the products table. Each product will have exactly one manufacturer. The room database has two tables, one for each feature.

As the app already has a lot of files I am not sure how to share the files so that you can see, what I already have implemented.

Maybe somebody has an example for me how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the 1-Many relationship by adding a new column to the product to store the ID of the manufacturer, perhaps with a Foreign Key constraint defined.

Something along the lines of:-

```
@Entity
data class Manufacturer(
    @PrimaryKey
    val manufacturerId: Long?=null,
    val manufacturerName: String
    // etc
)
@Entity(
    /* Foreign key constrains are option but suggested as they enforce referntial integrity*/
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Manufacturer::class,
            parentColumns = ["manufacturerId"],
            childColumns = ["manufacturerIdReference"],
            /* On Update/Delete actions are optional but help to automatically maintain referenttial integrity */
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey
    val productId: Long?=null,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true) /* Optional but may be more efficient */
    val manufacturerIdReference: Long,
    val productName: String
    // etc
)
```

Obviously you would want to be able to retrieve a Product with it's Manufacturer, so a POJO like:-

```
data class ProductWithManufacturer(
    @Embedded
    val product: Product,
    @Relation(
        entity = Manufacturer::class,
        parentColumn = "manufacturerIdReference",
        entityColumn = "manufacturerId"
    )
    val manufacturer: Manufacturer
)
```

- Where `@Embeded` is for the core object; and
- `@Relation` is used by Room to build a query that it uses to get the related object(s).
- You could have a POJO for getting a Manufacturer with the Products by reversing the above.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. But I think the database model is not the problem. The problem is that I have two different features (manufacturers and products) and I have no idea how to get access from the the products feature to the data  from the manufacturer feature, so that I will be able to fill the dropdown list with a list of manufacturers.